# ACF and PACF interpretation

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, acf-pacf

[image: ACF of my dataset[![][1]] Click for ACF image [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hZuA.jpg)

These are my ACF and PACF of my data set . Can any one help me determine whether the data is stationary ? if so What order of AR , MA ?

Answer (score 2):

The periodicity in your (P)ACF plots strongly suggests seasonality of length slightly less than 0.02 of the cycle you defined. Since $7/365\approx 0.019$, I suspect that you have daily data, which you specified as `frequency=365`. We can't say much more.

Note that it is not very good practice to examine (P)ACF plots any more (the [box-jenkins](/questions/tagged/box-jenkins) approach). Nowadays, it's better to choose models based on AIC, after determining any necessary differencing using appropriate methods. I suggest you look at `?forecast::auto.arima` and [*FPP2*](https://otexts.org/fpp2/).

If you do have daily data with possible intra-yearly seasonality, you may want to look at our [multiple-seasonalities](/questions/tagged/multiple-seasonalities) tag.

Comment: Yes its a daily data I used the auto.arima function and it resulted in following  Series: myts 
ARIMA(1,0,0) with non-zero mean 

Coefficients:
         ar1      mean
      0.2103  236.0485
s.e.  0.0284   65.4923

sigma^2 estimated as 3181549:  log likelihood=-10569.71
AIC=21145.41   AICc=21145.43   BIC=21160.65

Comment: Try clarifying that the more relevant seasonal cycle is of length 7, rather than 365: `ts(..., frequency=7)`. I suspect that `auto.arima()` will then give you a seasonal model based on this frequency.